# How can I determine my voice class?

Tags: voice

I went to a music class and the teacher said my range is A3-C5. How can I use the knowledge of my range to determine what my voice class is (e.g., alto, bass, suprano etc.)?

Also, can I be a singer and what is the most suitable genre for me?

Here is a video of me singing *I'm Not The Only One* by Sam Smith:

Comment: The answer to "can I be a singer" is "yes", all you have to do is sing. If you mean "can I be a professional singer?" then none of us can answer that. Either way I suggest you edit your question and remove that and also remove the question about what genre you should sing, since that will be opinion based and could cause your question to be closed.

Comment: This is not a video. It's an audio recording presented on YouTube. We can't see you. We need to know your gender and your age. This is essential information to determining your voice type.

Answer (score 2):

There are several online resources for determining what your voice classification is (here's [one example](http://choirly.com/whats-my-voice-type/)). Here's a breakdown, based on the linked web site, of the voice classes by **typical** range (just a guideline) and gender:

- Female, B3 to C6 - Soprano
- Female, G3 to A5 - Mezzo Soprano
- Female, G3 to F5 - Alto (not on the linked web site)
- Female, E3 to F5 - Contralto
- Male, G3 to C6 - Countertenor
- Male, C3 to B4 - Tenor
- Male, G2 to G4 - Baritone
- Male, D2 to E4 - Bass

Based on that list, and guessing that you are male, you can probably describe yourself as a tenor, which is a common range for men.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine your vocal range based on one visit to a music class and one comment from a music teacher.

You have also not told us your gender and your age, and these are needed to answer the question. If you are male, then, boys can be sopranos or altos, but after their voice changes when puberty arrives, they will develop into one of the following: bass, baritone or tenor. If you are right in the middle of puberty, it may not be entirely obvious which voice type you will develop into.

The best way to answer the question as to your voice type is to have several lessons with a voice teacher, or at least to spend some months singing in a choir and getting feedback from your choir director.

Most of the time an experienced teacher can guess at your voice type, broadly falling into soprano or alto for a woman, or tenor or bass for a male *after puberty*, but this is not always the case. You may be capable of singing in a lower or higher register, but this may not be obvious because you haven't learned how to sing any higher or lower notes yet.

I have observed that many choirs have women in the alto section who are in fact sopranos but they don't know it, because they never took private voice lessons. When they joined a choir, somebody told them they sounded like an alto and they never questioned it or did any work to find out if that were actually true. Years later they are still stuck in the wrong section. Similarly there are lots of men in the bass section of choirs who are really tenors but they don't know it either. Perhaps they decided that voice lessons or practicing singing outside of choir rehearsal was not for them, and they didn't care enough to do anything about it.

If you really want to know what your true voice type is, and realize your full potential as a singer, you need some private voice lessons to work this out.

Since you are just approaching the idea of singing for the first time, it's way too early to say what the most suitable genre of music is for you to sing. If you have a good voice, you can learn to sing most any style of music if you practice effectively and get lessons where they are needed.

For now, simply keep singing, in a music class or choir or in private lessons if you care enough to pursue them, and don't worry about the larger questions. You will develop answers to them as you gain experience singing.